# Using on chip I2C on NXP P89LPC954

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, microprocessor, smbus

I am trying to use on chip I2C on NXP P89LPC954 microcontroller(80C51 based) for voltage monitoring.

1. I have two voltage monitoring chips of same kind(same chip with same register address) connected to I2C pins of microcontroller.
2. Now in order to write to one of the chip how can i send address and data to that specific chip registers.What i mean is both are connected to the same pins of microcontroller(SDA,SCL).
   [image]

Microcontroller used :NXP P89LPC954

Voltage monitor ic   :MAX6656

Interface            : I2C

Comment: Please provide a part number for the voltage monitor ICs

Comment: Voltage monitor ic :MAX6656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More specifically, you need to set the ADD0 and ADD1 pins of your two MAX6656's to different values. These set the slave address when the MAX6656 powers up. See Table 5 in the MAX6656 datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want the Voltage Monitoring ICs would need the ability to change the slave address. If the slave addresses are different then the master can quarry either chip independently. Look at Table 5 in the data sheet. The Table shows what pin configuration of pins ADD0 and ADD1 will give what slave address.